# clearTimeout doesn't stop the loop

Tags: javascript

My script:

```
var pics = [ "mads.jpeg" ,"niggs.jpg", "rits.jpeg"];

var totalPics = pics.length;    
var frame = document.getElementById("photos");    
var i = 0;   

function loop() {

    if(i > (totalPics - 1)){                   
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);        
    }

    frame.innerHTML = '<img id="i" class="image" src="real_bs/'+pics[i]+'" />';
    i++;

    loopTimer = setTimeout(loop, 300);

}

loop();
```

When `i` exceeds `totalPics - 1`, the loop is not stopping, rather a small undefined image is being displayed. Why is `clearTimeout(loopTimer)` not stopping it? Is this an issue with variable scope?

Comment: Your code clears the timeout, but then it always starts it up again. You don't really need to use `clearTimeout()` anyway; just return from the function.

Comment: but initally i = 0 right ?

Comment: `   if(i >= (totalPics - 1)){                   
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);        
    } `

Comment: @Pointy or better yet not start a new iteration when you don't have to!

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to call `clearTimeout` - just arrange to *only* call `setTimeout` if there are more iterations left.  A timeout that's never started doesn't have to be cleared:

```
(function loop() {

    frame.innerHTML = '<img id="i" class="image" src="real_bs/' + pics[i] + '" />';

    if (++i < totalPics) {
        setTimeout(loop, 300);
    }

})();  // invoke immediately
```

Comment: the problem still persists - i removed the line of code `clearTimeout(loopTimer)`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a simple return after your clearTimeout method call. Like this

```
if(i > (totalPics - 1)){                   
    clearTimeout(loopTimer);
    return;
}
```